# How to get radio button values from SQL Server into C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am bit confused with getting radio button values from a SQL Server database into my form using C# code.

Here is an example:

```
if (optIsActiveYes.Checked) { 
    optIsActiveYes.Value = dt.Rows["Yes"].ToString(); 
}
```

Please help me with example.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confussed now. Do you mean you table has a bit field?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you wrote already to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi..                                                              if (optIsActiveYes.Checked)
                        {
                            optIsActiveYes.Value = dt.Rows["Yes"].ToString();
                        }

Comment: @indra: please **do not post** code to comments! It's really really hard to read - instead: **update your original question** by editing it!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
optIsActiveYes.Checked =  Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows["Yes"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It is mentioned for   radiobutton  and radiobuttonlist.

if (RadioButton1.Checked)

```
    { string str1 = RadioButton1.Text; }

    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex > -1)

    { string str2 = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text; }
```